# delay when close tab JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, tabs

I have a multimedia project.

It's about an old cabaret in the town, when a user open the page, there will be theater curtains, and a projection (like the old ones). When the user click's the projection the courtains will open starting a song, also there will be text information, images, etc.

it's finished, but i like to make something about closing the tab.

i want this: when the user press the (x) to close the tab, make a delay, for example, 3 seconds, on that 3 sec, the courtains will close, so to the end of animation (i know how to make the animation) the tab close. Something like "that's all folks", but only 3 or 2 secs.

i've searched alot, but only find how to make a textbox asking if you want to close the tab, tried to modify the code to make the animation, but nothing happends (just close the current tab).

Comment: It's impossible to delay the user from closing your website.  Unfortunately this can't be done.

Comment: thanks for the answer Scott Kaye, i think that will be a nice "ending".

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of 2 seconds pause (2 000 ms)

```
//code before the pause is started
    setTimeout(function(){
        //do what you need here after defined amount of time
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: i've tried this:

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('HAAAAAAAAAA');
    }, 2000);
};

Answer (score 1):

I use this method when I need the user to logout from server before closing the tab (and in all the other cases: page refresh, back button or browser closed).
It's not 100% guaranteed, but if you set an amount of time large enough, you are quite sure that your code is being executed before closing the tab.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // your code goes here
    // .......
    var start = Date.now(), now = start;
    var delay = 500; // msec
    while (now - start < delay) {
        now = Date.now();
    }
    // this is needed to avoid to show a confirmation prompt
    delete e['returnValue'];
});
```